# Product of asymptotic series of differing variables. Is it asymptotic? What is the order?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, divergent-series

Suppose we have asymptotic series
$$
f(x)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^{-n},\quad x\to\infty
$$
and
$$
g(y)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\, y^{-n},\quad y\to\infty.
$$
Is the product
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}\,x^{-\ell} \,y^{\ell-k},\quad x,y\to\infty
$$
an asymptotic expansion for $f(x)g(y)$?  If so, what is the order of the $k$th term?

I know this is true if $x=y$ in the sense that
$$
f(x)g(x)\sim\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell} \,x^{-k}+\mathcal O\{x^{-N-1}\},\quad x\to\infty
$$
is an asymptotic series.

I thought, perhaps, I could recast the problem in terms of polar coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto(\rho\cos\varphi,\rho\sin\varphi)$ such that
$$
f(\rho\cos\varphi)g(\rho\sin\varphi)\sim\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell(\varphi) b_{k-\ell}(\varphi) \,\rho^{-k}+\mathcal O\{\rho^{-N-1}\},\quad \rho\to\infty.
$$